# After local storage.getItem even thow i have more than one records i always get array.lenght 1

Tags: jquery, arrays, local-storage

I have a menu that each time I click on a link it adds its index in an array and I save this array in my local storage. When i refresh the page I have a script that takes that data back and stores them again in my array. Although my script is working and when I alert my table it shows me all the records that have benn added in the process, when i ask for my table.length it always return 1. What am i doing wrong;;;;

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    var history = [ ]; // This is my array
```

Here I get my data from the local storage after page refresh

```
    var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem('history');
    var times = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
```

Here I add the records in my array if there is any

```
    if (times !== null) {
    history.push(times);
    }

    alert(history.length); // it always return 1
```

This is the click function that gets the index of the menu item it was clicked and adds it in my array and saves the array in the local storage

```
      var pushed = $('.active li');
      pushed.click (function() {
        var index = pushed.index( this );
        history.push(index);
        localStorage.setItem("history", JSON.stringify(history));
     });

    });
```

I would also like to mention that when i look at my local storage from the developer tools after adding more than one record the data shows in this way

```
 [[0],1]
```

Here is my html

```
    <nav class="navigation active">

        <ul>

            <li><a href="index2.html"><span>Privacy</span></a></li>

            <li><a href="index.html"><span>Sitemap</span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><span>Newsletter</span></a></li>

            <li class="account"><a href="#"><span>My Account</span></a></li>

        </ul>

    </nav>
```

Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: problem is that you add array into array`[].push([1,2])` which turns into `[[1,2]]`, use `history.concat(times)`

Comment: You are right but i solved it with a very simple way, I deleted if (times !== null) {
    history.push(times);
    } and replaced it with history = times and it worked perfect!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i pushed an array inside another array

```
if (times !== null) {
history.push(times);
}
```

I deleted that part and replaced it with

```
history = times;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this part should be like that :

```
  var pushed = $('.active li'),
      history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history'));
  pushed.click (function() {
    var index = pushed.index( this );
    history.push(index);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("history", JSON.stringify(history));

});
```